# Naming conflict when editing std

Tags: c++

I have a templated class `function<D, R>`, and I am trying to make a hash for it like so:

```
namespace std {
    template<typename D, typename R>
    template<>
    struct hash<function<D, R>>
    {
        // hash related stuff
    };
}
```

However, `function` collides with a class inside of std. Can I avoid this without renaming `function` and without having to create a templated Hash struct?

Comment: `struct hash<jerry::function<D, R>>` ... or whatever you call your namespace.

Comment: Why do you want to define it in the `std` namespace?

Comment: @nielsen • defining a `std::hash` for a user defined type is one of the few allowed extension points in the `std` namespace.  (Unless, unbeknownst to me, that has been deprecated or disallowed in recent standards for C++17 or C++20 or C++future.)

Comment: @nielsen That way I can use std::unordered_map

Comment: @Eljay Is this not a templated hash? I specifically mentioned not wanting to use this.

Comment: Well it is your code, you can do it however you want.  But that may involve you making your own containers instead of using the ones provided with the standard C++ library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ensure that the name lookup finds your class by using a fully qualified name instead of an unqualified name. Like this:

```
struct hash<::some::ns::function<D, R>>
```

It doesn't necessarily have to be fully qualified as long as it is unambiguous with any `function` declared in other namespaces.

Comment: Anything we can do if `function` does not live in a namespace?

Comment: @JerryHalisberry All names are in a namespace.

Comment: Ah, I did not know that. Thank you

Comment: `::` is a namespace. (Just a potential clarification for future readers)